# Call explicitly jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below jquery code, this calls when COUNTRY dropdown value get changed, but i need to call this event when i set the value to country dropdown,
is there any way to call this piece of code explicitly?

```
//set the change event for the country.
 $( "#COUNTRY" ).change(
      function() { 
        alert("in country change");
          // code to change the other dropdown values based on country
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.trigger()` or `.change()`:

```
 $('#COUNTRY').trigger('change');
```

or

```
 $('#COUNTRY').change();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call with `chagne()` and use `trigger("change")` on the dropdown (select)

```
$("#COUNTRY").change();
```

*OR*

```
$("#COUNTRY").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in jquery to explicitly call an event

```
$( "#COUNTRY" ).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#COUNTRY" ).trigger('change')
```